# Combined two queries result into one resluts

Tags: mysql

[Here is the result table images.I want to print out these available units using sum  function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21wRB.png)

1) Query No 1

```
SELECT  SUM(inventory.inn-inventory.out_inv) AS available_units 
FROM  products
LEFT JOIN inventory on inventory.product_id=products.product_id
GROUP BY inventory.product_id
```

2) Query No 2

```
 SELECT products.product_manual_id,products.product_name,products.product_description,products.product_unit,product_categories.category_name,products.product_image,price.cost ,price.selling_price  
FROM products,stores,product_taxes ,price,product_categories

WHERE (products.store_id=2  AND  product_taxes.tax_id=products.tax_id AND price.product_id=products.product_id OR product_categories.category_id=products.category_id) AND (products.product_id <=31 AND products.product_id >=29  ) 
GROUP By products.product_name ORDER BY products.product_name ASC
```

I want to combined these two queries' results. How can I tackle it? I have been trying many alternatives. Whoever gives me an answer will be appreciated by me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two  select table join by product_id

```
    select t1.*, t2.* from ( 
    SELECT 
          products.product_id
        , SUM(inventory.inn - inventory.out_inv) AS available_units 
    FROM  products
    LEFT JOIN inventory on inventory.product_id=products.product_id
    GROUP BY inventory.product_id
    ) t1 
    left join (
     SELECT 
       products.product_manual_id
      ,products.product_id
      ,products.product_name
      ,products.product_description
      ,products.product_unit
      ,product_categories.category_name
      ,products.product_image
      ,price.cost 
      ,price.selling_price  
    FROM products,stores,product_taxes ,price,product_categories
    WHERE (products.store_id=2  
            AND  product_taxes.tax_id=products.tax_id 
            AND price.product_id=products.product_id 
            OR product_categories.category_id=products.category_id) 
    AND (products.product_id <=31 AND products.product_id >=29  ) 
    GROUP By products.product_name 

    ) t2 on t1.product_id = t2.product_id
    ORDER BY t2.product_name ASC
```

Comment: I have been try this , This eror occure during query run 'Unknown column 't1.products.product_id' in 'on clause' @scaisEdge

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi   answer  updated  hope is what you are looking for

Comment: Alot of thanks but it also does not work again unknown column eror occure .

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi   the same column  or another .. ?

Comment: Thanks  ,Thanks  alots After  many  alternatives  and with your help . I got desired  results.Your last answere work but in t1 i were put self join but  in my situation left join work correctly not self join give desired results.@scaiseEdge

Comment: Okey i will mark your  question. But in my siuation work my  querry. self join mean = (sign) we join two table

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi   .   many thanks  ... but if yo can  .. please update your question whit your working code .. so i can understand ..